# Regex for key : value pair matching

Tags: regex

I would like to accomplish some pattern matching in java with...

**Regex pattern used**

```
(?<key>[^:]+):(?<value>[^:]+)(?:,|$)
```

**Text to parse:**

```
a long key: with some long value, KeyA: ValueA, KeyB: ValueB, KeyC: ValueC, ValueD, ValueE, some text and https://www.example.orf, KeyF: 84,3 kg, KeyG: 34,3 x 234,3 x 54 cm
```

**Desired result:**

```
a long key: with some long value
KeyA: ValueA
KeyB: ValueB
KeyC: ValueC
ValueD
ValueE
some text and https://www.example.orf
KeyF: 84,3 kg
KeyG: 34,3 x 234,3 x 54 cm
```

the url breaks the whole thing unfortunately
and i dont know how to extract those "keyless" values

thanks in advance,

fritz

Comment: I think it's rather complicated because you are having keys with spaces and in the values you allow the `:` and `,` chars. That makes it rather complicated! But you could try to make it a bit more strict by having keys only containing chars, underscores and hyphens. And you could also use `: ` (with the space after) as separator. It would help but not handle all cases. Is the text to parse always such crap? or could it be regenerated with something cleaner, such as putting the value between quotes, like it would be done in CSV or JSON?

Comment: I'm perplexed. If you just want the multiline string that you show as the "desired result" just split the original string on the regex `, +` (match a comma followed by one or more spaces). [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8wHJ77/1)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure my answer is correct, you probably have to ask Wiktor Stribiżew who is the best I know, but I got this one:

https://regex101.com/r/dGBQ4s/1

The pattern: `/[,\s]*(?<key>\b[^:,]+?): (?<value>.*?(?=$|,\s+\b[^:,]+: ))/g`

I started off by thinking that the key was any char except `:` and `,` and that the `\b` for word boundary could help ignoring spaces between the items. This is why I added `[,\s]*` in front of it in order to *"eat"* them.

Then for the value, I used a non-greedy match with `.*?` to match anything but it had to be followed by the positive lookahead that could either match the end of the string or a next key definition.

Comment: that's neat, thanks this will help.
for those "keyless"-values i will write some code to extract those from the value-part of the match e.g. find first comma + space substring to the end of value

the url-problem could be solved this way that's great thanks

Comment: just a little notice, this expression will not work if the pair is equal to something like 
key:value

the express must be changed from 

[,\s]*(?<key>\b[^:,]+?):(?<value>.*?(?=$|,\s+\b[^:,]+:))

to

[,\s]*(?<key>\b[^:,]+?):(?<value>.*?(?=$|,\s+\b[^:,]+: )) the last colon + space is essential

Comment: Yes, I assumed that the key was followed by the semicolon and space, like in your example. You'll probably have to play with the regex to match all these crapy variants. Hope you'll get it working and glad it helped you!